# Hyper ledger multi host setup error while running order and peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

In the hyper ledger fabric, I am working on multi-host set up in the server, In my case, I used 3 servers, each server we have 1 orders,1 peers and 1 cli, So I have up orders and peers for the first server , I am getting successfully initialized.

But checking in docker ps I am getting status like this
Example:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
c1e18e1ff24e        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           12 minutes ago      Exited (2) 12 minutes ago                       orderer.example.com
3bf3d1d6f5e4        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   12 minutes ago      Exited (1) 12 minutes ago                       peer0.org1.example.com
```

After I checked

```
docker logs c1e18e1ff24e
```

error like this

> panic: Unable to bootstrap orderer. Error reading genesis block file: read /var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block: is a directory

How to solve this issue?

Comment: `orderer.genesis.block` is a directory not a `genesis block`. check the mapping in `docker-compose.yml` file. check `networks/channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block` mapping. Here in your case `genesis.block` is a directory. share `orderer` config.

Comment: This error comes when your BYFN scripts have failed for some reason. On Windows I've seen 'cryptogen' commands did not work when in SH file. I had to pull them out separately and run them, tweak couple of SH files. So, carefully read through all the logs emitted, compare them with the SH files, identify failing command. Check if that can be run separately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you send me the correct genesis block path, because if I give this path again getting the same error

Comment: I solve this issue and  Actually I am using basic network version 2.0, I got an error while running on chain-code unable to connect organization 2

Answer (score 0):

Generally this situation happened due to the wrong mapping of peers and orderers volumes mapping in docker-compose.yml file.

Please map the the volumes in docker-compose.yml file properly to get rid of this situation.

Comment: I faced the similar issue, in my case my wrong mapping was "../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block" and my correct mapping was "channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you send me the correct genesis block path, because if I give this path again getting the same error

Comment: I solve this issue and  Actually I am using basic network version 2.0, I got an error while running on chain-code unable to connect organization 2

Answer (score 0):

Exact Error in orderer log:

```
panic: unable to bootstrap orderer. Error reading genesis block file:
  read /var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block: is a directory
```

Symptom:

First go to channel-artifacts and list all file and Dir.

```
ls -ltr
```

Now check genesis.block details

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root    4096 Aug 30 13:25 genesis.block
```

There must be 'd' in start of permission which says genesis.block is directory not the file.

The problem is in your `configtx.yaml` last section 'profiles'.

Check the profiles thoroughly. In my case consortium name below TwoOrgsChannel was different then forth last line of profile sub section 'Consortium'. Consortium name should be same in second line from top and fourth last line of the profile section.

Due to which it was not generating the genesis.block file and it was creating the directory instead.